# what is Psychic window in relation to VC++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I saw above question in

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/67202

Then i searched in Google, got below links.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/470448e8-546f-4f5a-82b1-abbafe64b856

http://forums.windowsforum.org/index.php?showtopic=28783

I had some fun :D but no answer.

Is there anything called Psychic window ?

Comment: A psychic Window is a window which professes an ability to perceive information hidden from the normal windows through extrasensory perception (ESP). The phychic capabilities of these windows have however never been proven in a test lab environment, though rumors persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is such a thing, i've never heard of it.  Sounds totally made up, though.  It's likely a joke.